# Apply one input to tensorflow session and get output

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, mnist

I am running the sample [MNIST handwritten numbers tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#evaluating-our-model).

How can I **activate the session with the first test** MNIST image and hopefully **get the expected output**?

When I do this:

```
print(sess.run(tf.convert_to_tensor(mnist.test.images[0])))
```

I get a 784-long tensor with weights(guessing):

```
...
...
...
0.94901967  0.99607849  0.99607849  0.20392159  0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
0.47450984  0.99607849  0.99607849  0.8588236   0.15686275  0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
0.47450984  0.99607849  0.81176478  0.07058824  0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
...
...
...
```

My expected output would be 7 in this format:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the images (`mnist.train.images`) are `784 = 28 x 28`  dimensional vectors. What you are looking for are labels (`mnist.test.labels`), which are indeed `10`-dimensional:

```
In [29]: mnist.test.labels[0]
Out[29]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.])
```

By the way, these arrays are just regular numpy arrays, you don't need to use tf session to print them.

Comment: Oh, I get that, but how can I compute one label from one input(784 array)? Without accessing the label. Like, say I wrote a digit, scanned it and wanted to detect which number it is.

Comment: Well, you train a model (e.g. the one described in a tutorial), and then calculate its output on a given input, e.g.
`print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[10:20]}))`

Comment: Nice, thank you. Is there maybe a shortcode to run just one input - `sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[0:1]})`

Comment: Yes, what you wrote should work. In the end it depends on the model, but it is typical that a model accepts a list of inputs and returns a list of outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the predictions, wich have been stored to y in this phase :

```
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
```

They are probabilities (thanks to softmax) and you have to take the best to get predicted answer:

```
tf.argmax(y, 1)
```

In your case this should give you the prediction for the first image:

```
tf.argmax(y[0],1)
```

Comment: What would I do if I had a fresh image of handwritten number and wanted to detect which number it is?